# Sending preprints to colleagues

Tags: publications, collaboration, preprint

I recently submitted a journal article and it is under review. I have not heard back yet. I am in contact with a potential collaborator, and I think it would be beneficial for her to read I have in the submitted paper. Is it advisable to send out preprints that have yet to be published? Rejection of a submitted manuscript is always a possibility.

Comment: This is very common in math, where papers take a long time to be reviewed. In fact, the second thing I do after submitting a preprint to a journal is send it out to colleagues/mentors I think would find it relevant. Like "Hi, how are you, this preprint may be of interest." (The first thing is post to arXiv.)

Comment: It's advisable to do it even before submission.  See e.g. http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/1608/etiquette-and-guidelines-for-sending-pre-published-work-to-other-people and http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/14882/soliciting-pre-submission-manuscript-comments-from-people-who-could-later-be-pee

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I frequently privately share pre-prints that have not been published anywhere (not even pre-print servers) with colleagues who I know and trust.  I often won't say where it's under review, however, just because it's kind of pointless to say a place it might be rejected from.

In fields where pre-print archives like arXiv.org are used, once you've put it up in such a pre-print server, it's got a public date stamp and it's entirely reasonable and safe to share with anybody.  Likewise, once a paper has been accepted and is just waiting to appear, I feel it safe to share pre-prints privately.

With something that is under review and not on a pre-print server, however, I would not share it with people who I do not already know and trust.